# Change all vuetify component text and background colors

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

Guys do you know how can i change all Vuetify component text and background colors?

i used custom theme but is not fixed.

:)

```js
const myCustomLightTheme = {
    dark: false,
    colors: {
        background: "#FFFFFF",
        surface: "#FF0000",
        primary: "#FF0000",
        "primary-darken-1": "#FF0000",
        secondary: "#03DAC6",
        "secondary-darken-1": "#018786",
        error: "#B00020",
        info: "#2196F3",
        success: "#4CAF50",
        warning: "#FB8C00"
    }
};

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
    theme: {
        defaultTheme: "myCustomLightTheme",
        themes: {
            myCustomLightTheme
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the entry for `on-background` (and probably `on-primary`, `on-surface`, etc):

```
const myCustomLightTheme = {
  dark: false,
  colors: {
    ...,
    'on-background': '#00f00f',
    'on-primary': '#ff0',
  },
}
```

Use the inspector to figure out which variable is used. In the screenshot, you can see that text color on the input is set through the `--v-theme-on-background` variable:

[image]

(`v-theme-` is a prefix added by Vuetify, the corresponding variable is `on-background`)

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)